# Samba file: User can access one share, but not another despite identical permissions & smb.conf config

Tags: permissions, samba, share

Using Debian 10 Buster (specifically version **Linux HAL 5.4.28-odroidxu4 #20.02.7 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 26 23:36:03 CET 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux**)

I have an external drive mounted using an entry in /etc/auto.master, mounted to "/externaldrive".

On this drive, I currently have 3 configured shares:

/externaldrive/data shared as Data

/externaldrive/music shared as Music

/externaldrive/videos shared as Videos

'Data' is accessible by everyone, and this share is accessible from a Win10 machine and Android device.

'Music' is restricted to user 'media', and can successfully be logged into from a Win10 machine & Android device.

'Videos' is visible as a share, but cannot be logged into from either device, on the basis that the permissions appear to be preventing access.

What I don't understand is that the share config for Music & Videos is identical, as as the folder permissions for the 2 folders.

testparm doesn't appear to show any problems:

```
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Registered MSG_REQ_POOL_USAGE
Registered MSG_REQ_DMALLOC_MARK and LOG_CHANGED
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[Data]"
Processing section "[Videos]"
Processing section "[Music]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions

# Global parameters
[global]
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[Data]
        force user = nobody
        path = /externaldrive/data
        read only = No


[Videos]
        path = /externaldrive/videos
        read only = No
        valid users = media


[Music]
        path = /externaldrive/music
        read only = No
        valid users = media
```

My smb.conf file is very basic:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP

[Data]
path = /externaldrive/data
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
force user = nobody

[Videos]
path = /externaldrive/videos
valid users = media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no

[Music]
path = /externaldrive/music
valid users = media
browsable = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
```

And folder permissions are as follows:

```
drwxrwsrwx+  5 root users  4096 Jul 15  2019 data
drwxrws---+  7 root users  4096 Apr 23 08:17 music
drwxrws---+  8 root users  4096 Apr 23 08:10 videos
```

I have tried applying chcon as per [Samba - can access 1 share but not the other. Same config](https://serverfault.com/questions/805012/samba-can-access-1-share-but-not-the-other-same-config):

```
chcon -t samba_share_t /externaldrive/videos
```

However received the following error:

```
chcon: can't apply partial context to unlabeled file '/externaldrive/videos'
```

I have also tried applying it recursusively as per http://redhatshiju.blogspot.com/2011/03/configuring-samba-server-in-linux.html:

```
chcon -Rt samba_share_t /externaldrive/videos
```

Unsurprisingly I receive the same error message, but for every single file/folder within this folder.

Any idea what the problem is and how I can resolve it? It may be linked to the context issue, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I've also tried `chcon -Rt -h system_u:object_r:samba_share_t /externaldrive/videos` but still get the same error message

Comment: And I'm running as root.